# REST request to server with jQuery

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, google-app-engine

**Problem:** error 404 arises. I think the problem is in forming URLs. Please, can anyone point out my mistake. I've been trying different variants for some time already but can't make it working.

Extract of my code:

*Server*

```
class Nearest_banks(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def main_func(self):
        body_values = {
           'radius': default_radius,
         }

        template = jinja_env.get_template('nearest_banks.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(body_values))


    def get(self):
        # some code here

    def post(self, entered_radius):
        return webapp2.Response('Done')

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
   webapp2.Route(r'/nearest_banks', handler=Nearest_banks, name='n_banks', handler_method='main_func'),
   webapp2.Route(r'/nearest_banks/default_radius', handler=Nearest_banks, name='default_radius', handler_method='get'),
   webapp2.Route(r'/nearest_banks/radius/(\d+)', handler=Nearest_banks, name='new_radius', handler_method='post'),
], config=session_module.config, debug=True)
```

*Client*

```
$( "#change_radius" ).click(function(){
    var new_radius = $("#radius").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: '/nearest_banks/radius/' + new_radius,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function() {
            $("#places").html("OKKK");
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("error");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
url_data= '/nearest_banks/radius/' + new_radius;
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: ''+url_data+'',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        xhrFields: {withCredentials:true},
        success: function() {
            $("#places").html("OKKK");
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("error");
        }
    });
```

Hope it helps

Comment: thanks.. but doesn't work with it also, I still think the problem is on server side

Comment: @Elena check if the requests are hitting your server or not

Comment: the requests are hitting and app works well when I change root to *'/nearest_banks/radius/'* both in *webapp2.WSGIApplication([])* and therefore in ajax request's url. So it works when I don't concatenate *new_radius* variable to url

Comment: @Elena I have updated the answer try if it works now.